# Why is a category column seen as a column of strings in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have a dataset containing ints, floats and strings. I (think I) converted all string to categories by the following statements:

```
for col in list (X):
    if X[col].dtype == np.object_:#dtype ('object'):
        X [col] = X [col].str.lower().astype('category', copy=False)
```

However, when I want to do input the data for a random forest model I get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'non-compliant by no payment'
```

The string 'non-compliant by no payment' occurs in a column named `X['compliance_detail']` and when I request its `dtype` I get `category`. When I ask its values:

```
In[111]: X['compliance_detail'].dtype
Out[111]: category
In[112]: X['compliance_detail'].value_counts()
Out[112]: 
non-compliant by no payment                        5274
non-compliant by late payment more than 1 month     939
compliant by late payment within 1 month            554
compliant by on-time payment                        374
compliant by early payment                           10
compliant by payment with no scheduled hearing        7
compliant by payment on unknown date                  3
Name: compliance_detail, dtype: int64
```

Does somebody know what's happening here? Why is a string seen in categorial data? Why is a dtype of Int64 listed for this column?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert to category type, the column remains in its original repr, but pandas keeps track of the categories.

```
s

0    foo
1    bar
2    foo
3    bar
4    foo
5    bar
6    foo
7    foo
Name: A, dtype: object

s = s.astype('category')
s

0    foo
1    bar
2    foo
3    bar
4    foo
5    bar
6    foo
7    foo
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [bar, foo]
```

If you want integer categories, you've a few options:

**Option 1**
`cat.codes`

```
s.cat.codes
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    0
6    1
7    1
dtype: int8
```

---

**Option 2**
*`pd.factorize`* (`astype` not required)

```
pd.factorize(s)[0]
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to factorize, that might save my day. But what I do not understand: what is the use of category when it is not recognized by the analyzing routines, e.g. RandomForestClassifier? This means that the pandas category is not comparable to R factor?

Comment: @Arnold category type was added to pandas quite recently. I don’t know enough about R to explain the difference.

Comment: There is more behind this than I thought. Reading the docs more carefully (what I should have done in the first place) made me compose my own answer.

Comment: @Arnold if it helped any, do consider accepting the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Well, it helped me to some extent for I did not know about factorize and it forced me to think more thoroughly about categories. I'd appreciate a reciprocal +1 for my answer.

Comment: @Arnold I upvoted both your question and answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I should have read the docs more carefully ;-) Most statistical tests in sklearn do not handle categories, as they do in R. RandomForestClassifiers can handle categories without problems in theory, the implementation in sklearn does not allow it (for now). My mistake was to think that they could do so, because theory says they can and it worked nicely in R. However, [the sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) says the following about the fit function:

> X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>
> The training input samples. Internally, its dtype will be converted to dtype=np.float32. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be converted into a sparse csc_matrix.

Thus no room for categories, and when they are factorized they are considered as numbers. [In this article](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/strings-as-features-in-decision-tree-random-forest) it is explained how categories work in Pandas and what their pitfalls are. I advise everybody who wants to use categories to read it, especially when with an R background. I hope this aspect will be improved as in the current situation one cannot make full use of some procedures.

Comment: In R, factors are native to the language. pandas, on the other hand, is a third party library. numpy is also like that but packages like sklearn are built on top of numpy. They don't recognize pandas though (it only works because DataFrames are collections of numpy arrays). So what is the point of having categories? It takes much less memory to store data like that. And hopefully someday ML libraries will use pandas' features.

Comment: Thanks you @ayhan, I was not aware of the memory aspect. And I do hope indeed ML libraries will use pandas categories for in the case of RandomForestClassifiers not doing so it hampers their power.